# Why is multisite rest API keep giving me results for root site only?

Tags: multisite, rest-api

I have a multisite wp installation and am trying to access the posts from the rest api for a subsite. I keep getting the results for the root site instead of the subsite. I'm using Postman to test the endpoints.

How do I get the results for the subsite instead of the root site in a wp mulitsite installation?

i.e. mysite.com
test.mysite.com -> same results as mysite.com

Comment: What URLs are you sending requests to?

Comment: notetonic.xyz and
dmiskovic.notetonic.xyz

Comment: `https://dmiskovic.notetonic.xyz/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` and `https://notetonic.xyz/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` are showing different posts for me. Are those the endpoints you're using?

Comment: what app are you using?

Comment: I'm just going to those URLs in Chrome.

Comment: you're right. i was missing the https. thanks bro!